# How to use data.table := operator without changing original table?

Tags: r, data.table

This might be a very silly question. But let's say I have `data.table` called `x <- data.table(c(1:5),c(2:6))`

Then I assign another variable to it: `y <- x`. How come when I do something to `y` using the `:=` operator it changes the original `x` data.table?

```
> x <- data.table(c(1:5),c(2:6))
> y <- x
> y <- y[,testing := V1 + V2]
> y
   V1 V2 testing
1:  1  2       3
2:  2  3       5
3:  3  4       7
4:  4  5       9
5:  5  6      11
> x
   V1 V2 testing
1:  1  2       3
2:  2  3       5
3:  3  4       7
4:  4  5       9
5:  5  6      11
```

Is there any way to use the `data.table` `:=` operator without this occurring?

Comment: Use  `y <- copy(x)` instead of `y <- x`..